# Change font size in Thunderbird inbox screen

Tags: windows-7

I want to know how to install the add-on feature in Thunderbird, using windows 7.  All searching attempts say go to tools and simply click on add-on.  It should be the third choice on the drop down window. This is not to be found on my computer.  Further internet searching also says that this feature may not be on all bowers, but achievable.  Restoring this feature suggest to be somewhat complicated and above my ability.   My ultimate end goal is to edit the font size on the inbox, sent and trash screens for Thunderbird.  If not through an add-on, is there another way to accomplish this?

Thank you
Michael way up in Oregon